# How to await in a chain?

Tags: node.js, promise

This is a Azure Function `httpTrigger` in node.js. How to wait for `f1()` finishes then calls `f2()`?

```
model.exports = main(param)  // async main plus await f1(param) don't wait either.
{
  f1(param)
  .then(
    good => f2(good, callback),  // execution jumps into f2 without waiting for f1 finishes
    bad => {...}
  );
}

async function f1(param)
{
  try
  {
    // await NOT wait here, 
    // but waits in Express
    await googlelib.verifyIdToken(something, (err, ok) =>
    {
      if (err) { return Promise.reject("Invalid"); }
      else     { return Promise.resolve("OK"); }
    });
  }
  catch (e) { return Promise.reject("catch"); }
}
```

Comment: Just `return googlelib.verifyIdToken(something);`, don't pass a callback at all.

Comment: What library is `googlelib` from?

Comment: When you pass a callback to `googlelib.verifyIdToken()`, it probably doesn't return a promise so the `await` doesn't accomplish anything.  Use a promise interface or a callback interface, NOT a combination of the two.  And, if you're expecting you're `async` function to return a promise that resolves when your asynchronous stuff is done, then ONLY use promise interfaces inside that function as plain callbacks don't play with the `async` function at all.

Comment: @slebetman `const googlelib = new OAuth2Client(googleClientID);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Seems a very good idea, [google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Comment: @jfriend00 Appreciate the detailed info. I'm not very good with js, is there an example of promise interface I can study? Thank you!

Comment: @Jeb50 - I need a link to some doc on the `.verifyIdToken()` function.  Can you provide that?  Or provide a link to the NPM module that it comes from?  I need to see if it has a built-in promise interface or if you need to wrap it in a promise to give it a promise interface.

Comment: @jfriend00 [Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) to `.verifyIdToken()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `googlelib.verifyIdToken()` supports promises as a built-in part of its interface (as long as you do not pass it a callback), then you can change your code to this:

```
function f1(param) {
    return googlelib.verifyIdToken(something);
}
```

And, you will just directly return the promise that `googlelib.verifyIdToken()` provides, allowing the caller to use either `await` or `.then()` on the result that `f1(...)` returns.

---

If `googlelib.verifyIdToken()` does not support promises as a built-in part of its interface (when you do not pass it a callback), then you can "promisify" it yourself:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');

// create promisified interface .verifyIdTokenP
googlelib.verifyIdTokenP = promisify(googlelib.verifyIdToken);

// use that promisified interface
function f1(param) {
    return googlelib.verifyIdTokenP(something);
}
```

This process of manually promisifying a function works for any asynchronous API that supports the "nodejs asynchronous calling convention" where the function accepts a callback as the last argument and that callback will be called with two arguments as `callback(err, value)`.  If the asynchronous API works differently than this, then you can't use the `util.promisify()` function for it and would have to manually wrap it in your own promise.

Comment: Plain English, very easy to understand. Love it.